# ASP.NET with custom authentication won't get email from Google OAuth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, identity

My ASP.NET MVC system don't use ASP.NET Identity, so i went with full custom IPrincipal implementation. I have to use Google OAuth to authenticate on Google then do my own business on my external login callback.

The problem is that, after the user insert Google's e-mail and password ans successful login, in my external login callback, my application just won't get the user Claims from HttpContext.OwinContext().Authentication. Claims are empty and I only need user's e-mail.

[image: AuthenticationManager from OwinContext]

This is my Startup.Auth.cs

[image: System.Auth.cs]

There's no e-mail after login.

[image: Email isn't available in the user claims]

Assuming there's no bug in Google's OAuth, what did i do wrong?

One more thing: Sometimes (testing on other computers) the claims are returned to me with user's mail and some other data. But when i try to log with many different mails, they stop working too.

Below is my Google API config, i have enabled Google+ API, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

**EDIT**

Sometimes it works on Chrome's anonymous navigation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use async await method for google api auth like in google doc

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth

Comment: Please edit your answer with the relevant code/info from the link, in case it ever becomes dead.